# How to use a plain vanilla get/post method to obtain a authentication token in postman?

Tags: oauth-2.0, postman, pkce

I have been building a Duende Identity Server.
It is said that the Authorization Code Flow can be performed by visiting the following link
[image]
It looks like a Get method.
I can obtain an Authentication token using the Authorization tab without any issue.
[image]

But I just can't get a token for this Get-like request using the plain Get/Post-method.
[image]
What's different between the Get/Post-method and the "Configure New Token" setting? "Configure New Token" looks like a magic. How to achieve the same result using the Get/Post method?

Comment: Try x-www-form-urlencoded instead of query parameters.  However, doesn't this grant type require user interaction.  Doesn't the Postman Authorization helper open a web page for you to enter credentials.  You can't mimic that using a straight up  GET request which is why the helpers exist in the first place.